# A fixed point moves from $\infty$ to $-\infty$. Is this a bifurcation? If yes, what is the nature of bifurcation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chaos-theory

I am trying to study the pair of equations -

$
\dot{x} = y - ax \\
\dot{y} = -by + \dfrac{x}{1 + x}$

At $a = 0$, a fixed point at ($x = \infty, y = 1$), jumps over to ($x = -\infty, y = 1$). Do we call this a bifurcation?

Thanks.

Comment: Ohh. So you mean that if some fixed point is achieved at $t = \infty$ => it is not something we can observe => no use talking about bifurcations?

(I am still learning, so pardon me if I misunderstood)

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is the exact question I am solving :). 
One more question - did you know this page's location or did you google it? If you did indeed google it, what was the search query?